# Xhr request errors are not getting logged on Raygun platform

Tags: javascript, angular, raygun

I have integrated Raygun into one of my angular project and I'm also able to get some of the JavaScript related errors but not reference, syntax and type error on Raygun platform.

Though Raygun is not logging any xhr related errors on their platform. Got 403 Forbidden, 404 Not found and 500 internal server error on my network calls but Raygun did not reported any of those.

I have used the following steps for the setup:

1. Installed raygun4js package through npm using this command `npm install --save raygun4js`
2. Installed @types/raygun4js package through npm using this command `npm i --save-dev @types/raygun4js`
3. Added the following code

```
import { ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';

const VERSION_NUMBER = '1.0.0.0';
rg4js('apiKey', "***");
rg4js('setVersion', VERSION_NUMBER);
rg4js('enableCrashReporting', true);
export class RaygunErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  handleError(e: any) {
    rg4js('send', {
      error: e
    });
  }
}
```

I have checked on their docs and different online available resources for xhr related errors but got no help.

What can I more use to get xhr related errors. In case, if it is not possible, let me know that as well. Also please do let me know if I can or cannot get JavaScript reference, syntax and type error, framework related and performance related error also as I'm not getting that as well on Raygun platform.